# Cannot read properties of undefined of JoinRoom in zego Cloud

Tags: reactjs, zegocloud

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinRoom')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinRoom')
at myMeeting (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134:20)
at commitAttachRef (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:38136:24)
at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:38017:13)
at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:39016:13)
at commitLayoutEffects_begin (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:39005:11)
at commitLayoutEffects (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:38951:7)

Comment: can you please share the code that provide this error